# When I enter a number out of range, the loop returns the same value as when i enter a number from range. Why does it so happen?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function in a project that takes a response from user input.
If the number entered by the user is in the range, the program should print 'Your "X" is put in square number', answer). Otherwise, as I understand it, the loop should keep asking the question. How can I resolve this issue?

```
def ask_board_number(question):
    '''Asks enter the number from range'''

    answer = None
    while answer not in range(0, 9):
        answer = input(question)
    print('Your "X" is put in square number', answer)  
    return answer 

ask_board_number("\nInput the number of square, in that you want to put your 'X'. (0 - 8): ")
```

Answer (score 3):

`input` returns a `str` value, not an `int` value, so the containment check will always fail. You need to convert the `str` to an `int` first.

```
while answer not in range(0, 9):
    answer = int(input(question))
```